# How to connect two backgrounds of blocks with CSS or JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a difficult background image for website. I need to insert text after a certain point in the background.

The page is divided into two sections. The first block should contain one part of the image and the other block the other. I've tried splitting the background in two and giving them `background-size: cover`, but the connection between the images is disconnected.

It is important to note that the background must be fully responsive. How to do it? Help me please!

I attach an image of how everything should look.

[Image how it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpX2l.png)

Comment: where is the code that you already use? I dont udnerstand the problem you having tbh. Simply use a background image and then 2 divs in the front with a transperent backgroudn and fill them like you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use absolute positioning.  Put the location you want in the CSS. There are many options for the positioning. There is also the sticky valye, that is fixed in the viewport rather than on the image.

```
<style>
div.absolute { position: absolute;
  top: 100px; right: 100px; width: 200px; height: 100px; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>This div element has the image
  <div class="absolute">This div goes where you specify above in css</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I get the window height with javaScript, and used it as the flex-basis of main two parts. And added special text as absolute, near center as you want. You can use this structure.you can see the result with fullpage, it is responsive. I used background colors intentionally, so that you can see the layout.

```js
const height = window.outerHeight;
document.querySelector('.part1').style.flexBasis = height/2 + 'px';
document.querySelector('.part2').style.flexBasis = height/2 + 'px';
console.log(height);
```

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  background-image:url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/4992859/pexels-photo-4992859.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  
}
.container{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  color:white;
}
.part{
  opacity:.3;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  font-size:3rem;
}
.part1{
  background-color:red;
}

.part2{
  background-color:blue;
}

.special{
  font-size:1rem;
  position:relative;
  margin:50px auto 50px 50px;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="part part1">
    part1: here is the part one
  </div>
    <p class="special">Some special text</p>
  <div class="part part2">
    part2: here is the part two
  </div>
</div>
```